# How to add Microsoft Band functionality to a Silverlight phone application?

Tags: microsoft-band

Is there a way to integrate Microsoft Band with an existing Silverlight Windows Phone application? I have tried implementing an wrapper Windows Runtime Component for band functionality, but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft Band SDK does not support Silverlight-based Windows Phone applications, only Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT) based applications.